# Installing a linux distribution on QEMU

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu

I've recently started playing around with QEMU, and I'm trying to install a linux distro (Lighthouse64) on a qcow2 image. The thing that confuses me is I don't understand what's already on the image. Is it running BIOS? UEFI? Does it have an MBR/GPT? Should one be installed? 
The guides usually just skip this and say 'install the distribution after creating the disk image'.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which distribution is your host running?

Comment: @blissini 
It's running Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Okay, here's a step by step: I create a partition table and a single partition using GParted, then Lighthouse is being installed on it, it wipes the partition before the installation as well. Then I run a GRUBCONFIG which installs GRUB (I usually installed it on the same linux partition, but now I've tried installing it on the MBR). To clarify, now there **is** some sort of bootup process, but it's getting stuck in a different place. Still not sure whether GRUBCONFIG created the MBR, or just used the one already there.

Comment: I've just now realized that I'm creating the MBR during the GParted partition table creation (it's just called msdos and not MBR)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The guides don't mention anything because you don't need to do anything: create the blank image, start the installer (give Qemu the image using `-hda` and the installer ISO using `-cdrom`), and let the installer do its thing — it will partition the image and set up a bootloader as appropriate.